# Open multiple files using path = open() feature

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, dictionary, path

I have been using path = open(Testfilename) on a few of my beginning python scripts while I was learning about arrays. Now that I am working on dictionaries, I want to see if I can open up multiple files using this feature.

```
fav_cars = {}

for c in cars: #I have a few separate CSV files with different cars
    path = open()
```

I essentially want to loop around the different cars that user puts in. As mentioned above, I know how to open a single file, but I am trying to learn to open up multiple files.  I tried doing:

```
path = open('F-150.csv', 'Silverado.csv', 'Mustang.csv', 'Tesla.csv', 'r'),
```

but that did not work as I got an error code `TypeError: an integer is required`

UPDATE:

The car files are made of one column with the header called "colors". There are 6 rows for six colors: red, blue, yellow, black, white, green

```
cars = ['F-150','Silverado','Mustang','Tesla','Juke','Corolla']

fav_cars = {}   
for c in cars: 
    path = open () # wanting to open multiple files here
    car_colors = {} #colors for each car in cars
    for temp_dict in path:
         if not temp_dict.startswith("#"): #to get rid of the header "colors in the file
             if values in user_input: #value is the car color
                   car_colors.update({values})
                   fav_cars.update({c:car_colors})
```

I am only using the cars that the user inputs, user_inputs, when I called for it using raw_input. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: What would you want to do with the files once you have opened them?

Comment: Can you provide some example of the car csv files, expected user input, and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
fav_cars = {}

for c in cars:
    with open(c, 'r') as f:
       fav_vars[c] = f.readlines()
```

builtin `open` function expects only one file as an argument, second one is the file mode for your opening.

Comment: I did this but get the error AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'startswith'. I used : if not temp_dict.startswith("#") so I can remove the headers.

Comment: I think you try to operate on files' content before reading them. I modified my answer to add content of the files to list insted of the file objects.

Comment: Hm. fav_cars is still only giving me the output of {}.

Comment: @Caroline.py, you never use fav_cars  in your own code so how are we supposed to know what to do with it?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I apologize. I am new to dictionaries. I was assuming this would open the files and set it as a dictionary called fav_cars but forgot to use fav_cars.update({values}), where values is a list of colors in column format within each car file.

Comment: @Caroline.py. I think you will need to add some sample input and expected output as your actual use case is a lot different to what you have in your question.

Comment: @Caroline.py I did another edit, now dictionary will have filenames as keys and list of lines of each files as a values.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham please see my update. I am using car names as key and color as values if I did this correctly.

Comment: @Caroline.py This is probably not the core issue here, but i believe you should be putting your file extensions behind your files.